# I am getting this error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

```
class Student(object):

    def__init__(self, name='', school='', grade=''): #This is where I get the error

        if not name:
          name = raw_input('what is the student\'s name: ')
        if not school:
          school = raw_input('What is the studnet\'s school: ')
        if not grade:
          grade = self.get_grade()
        self.name = name
        self.school = school
        self.grade = grade
        self.print_student()

    def get_grade(self):
        while True:
            grade = input('What is the student\'s grade: [K, 1-5]')
            if grade.lower() not in ['k','2','3','4','5']:
                print('I\'m sorry, but {} isn\'t valid.'.format(grade))
            else:
                return grade

    def print_student():
        print('Name: {}'.format(self.name))
        print('School: {}'.format(self.school))
        print('Grade: {}'.format(self.grade))

def main():
    student1 = Student()
    studnet2 = Student(name='Bethmi Amalya', grade = '5', school= 'Visakha Vidyalaya')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Looks like missing space. Try `def __init__` instead of `def__init__`

Comment: Thank you very much :) It worked. Im new to programming and thank you so much!

Comment: no problem. `Happy Coding`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have 2 issues in code :

1 . def__init__(.... , there should be a space between def keyword and **init**(
i.e `def __init__(...`
 2 . self should be passed to  def `print_student()` i.e `print_student(self)`: and all variable accesses should be with self e.g `self.name` etc in print_student function .

```
class Student(object):

    def __init__(self, name='', school='', grade=''): #This is where I get the error

        if not name:
          name = raw_input('what is the student\'s name: ')
        if not school:
          school = raw_input('What is the studnet\'s school: ')
        if not grade:
          grade = self.get_grade()
        self.name = name
        self.school = school
        self.grade = grade
        self.print_student()

    def get_grade(self):
        while True:
            grade = raw_input('What is the student\'s grade: [K, 1-5]')
            if grade.lower() not in ['k','2','3','4','5']:
                print('I\'m sorry, but {} isn\'t valid.'.format(grade))
            else:
                return grade

    def print_student(self):
        print('Name: {}'.format(self.name))
        print('School: {}'.format(self.school))
        print('Grade: {}'.format(self.grade))

def main():
    student1 = Student()
    studnet2 = Student(name='Bethmi Amalya', grade = '5', school= 'Visakha Vidyalaya')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) It worked. still new to prgramming

Comment: keep it up :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

#### In line 1: `def__init__(self, name='', school='', grade=''):`

> There is **no space** between `def` and `__init__`
>
> > Add a space to fix the syntax error.

#### Also:

Python 2 used `raw_input()`
Python 3 uses `input()`

> > [Link to Changes in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html)